# What is the command line to open html file in atom?

Tags: html, command-line, atom-editor

I would like to know how to open a html file in atom with the command line.

Now, if I do this for example:

```
open index.html
```

It open the file in my browser but I was wondering if there was a command to open it in Atom too.

I'm using a mac and chrome as browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not used Atom myself but I assume it is much like other software in that you can open a file from the terminal using it like so:

```
atom index.html
```